# Remove unnecessary repeated tags with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am using Python and BeautifulSoup to extract some text from html. I have some html that has text of the form

```
<h3><b> Abc </b><b> DEF </b> </h3>
```

I would like to remove the repeated b tag. Is there a quick way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

For bs4 this seems to work just fine

```
In [4]: soup.h3
Out[4]: <h3><b> Abc </b><b> DEF </b> </h3>

In [5]: soup.h3.text
Out[5]: u' Abc  DEF  '
```

check out the docs and the package here:
https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.org/en/latest/
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/beautifulsoup4